# What is the difference between lock-free and obstruction-free?

Tags: concurrency, terminology, lock-free

I am reading up on [Transactional Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_memory) (TM), and one of the papers I'm reading says[[1](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-15763-9_6)]:

> Indeed, it was two nonblocking algorithms, the obstruction-free DSTM and lock-free FSTM that reinvigorated STM research in the past decade.

I was under the impression that lock implied obstruction.  Apparently, I was wrong...

What is the difference between the terms "*lock-free*" and "*obstruction-free*"?

Comment: I described wait-freedom, lock-freedom, obstruction-freedom, blocking guarantees from practical point of view here:
http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/introduction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the definitions from Herlihy & Shavit's [The Art Of Multiprocessor Programing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123705916).

> A method is *wait-free* if it guarantees
>   that every call finishes its execution
>   in a finite number of steps.
>
> A method
>   is *lock-free* if it guarantees that
>   infinitely often some method call
>   finishes in a finite number of steps.
>
> A method is *obstruction-free* if, from
>   any point after which it executes in
>   isolation, it finishes in a finite
>   number of steps (method call executes in isolation if no other threads take steps).

All wait-free methods are lock-free, and all lock-free methods are obstruction-free.

Comment: According to the paper ["On the nature of progress" by Maurice Herlihy et al@OPODIS'2011 [Fig. 1]](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~shanir/progress.pdf), I am afraid it is not the case that `all lock-free methods are obstruction-free`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm has more explanation of the categories. Lock-free can include CAS retry loops. Obstruction free but not lock-free can involve cancelling another thread's attempted operation if they conflict with each other, apparently.